# Yeoman generator works except on Windows 10 with Node 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, yeoman-generator

I have a generator that works on Ubuntu, Mac, and Windows 10 with Node 8.

It also (reportedly) runs on Win10 with Node 10 when run on either mintty.exe or Git bash from the git package (https://git-scm.com/download/win).

However it hangs when run on Win10 with Node 10 on either PowerShell or command.exe.

The "prompting" method runs fine and the "this.prompt" promise resolves OK. The problem is the "writing" method" is never run.

You can see the problem by going to an empty folder and running

npm i -g @feathers-plus/cli
set DEBUG=gen*
feathers-plus generate app
and pressing Enter on all the prompts.

You can see https://github.com/feathers-plus/generator-feathers-plus/blob/master/generators/app/index.js#L173 is run, but not https://github.com/feathers-plus/generator-feathers-plus/blob/master/generators/app/index.js#L178 .

Before I start digging into the Yeoman source, has anyone run into something similar, does anyone have any thoughts on what the issue may be, any thoughts on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm running into this problem myself with feathers-plus/cli  I was able to run generate app, but now running generate authentication I get an error saying the generator will only run on node 10

Comment: Same problem. Windows 10 x64, cli 7.75, node 11.6.0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into the same issue with an in house generator.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. There have been reports from 3rd parties the problem lies within Inquirer.js. However no progress from Yeoman. I'm recommending people use nvm-windows  or the Windows Subsystem for Linux.